# Work calculation from Thomas' calculus...does the text contain an error?

Tags: calculus

Exercise 17 in section 6.5 in Thomas' Calculus, 12th edition, asks

"A vertical right-circular cylindrical tank measures 30ft high and 20ft in diameter.  It is full of kerosene weighing 51.2 lb/ft^3.  How much work does it take to pump the kerosene to the level of the top of the tank?"

Here is my solution:  The radius of the tank is 10ft.  The volume of the tank is therefore $\pi 10^2 \cdot 30$.  Therefore the weight of the kerosene is $51.2 \cdot \pi 10^2 \cdot 30 \approx 482549$ lbs.

Calculating the work by thinking about lifting the center of mass from the middle of the tank to the top (a distance of 15ft), we find that the work 
$W = force \cdot (distance) = 7.23823 \cdot 10^6$ ft-lbs.

However, the "back of the book" has an answer of 37306 ft-lbs.  This is orders of magnitude off from my answer!!  Can you tell me which one of us is in error?